# Runtime exception

Tags: android, runtimeexception

I am new to Java programming and this has me stumped. I get a runtime exception and a force close when my app starts. It did work before I made a lot of the code into arrays rather than singles. Can someone give me a clue what might be wrong?

```
07-15 16:30:29.441: INFO/ARMAssembler(61): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00001001_00000000 [ 91 ipp] (114 ins) at [0x38fe50:0x390018] in 1735976 ns
07-15 16:30:29.551: ERROR/gralloc(61): [unregister] handle 0x4910f0 still locked (state=40000001)
07-15 16:30:58.871: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(229): Shutting down VM
07-15 16:30:58.871: WARN/dalvikvm(229): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
07-15 16:30:58.871: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(229): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-15 16:30:59.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(229): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.golfandroid/com.example.golfandroid.GolfScoreActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-15 16:30:59.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(229):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
07-15 16:30:59.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(229):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
07-15 16:30:59.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(229):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
07-15 16:30:59.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(229):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
07-15 16:30:59.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(229):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-15 16:30:59.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(229):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-15 16:30:59.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(229):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
07-15 16:30:59.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(229):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 16:30:59.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(229):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-15 16:30:59.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(229):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-15 16:30:59.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(229):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-15 16:30:59.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(229):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-15 16:30:59.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(229): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-15 16:30:59.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(229):     at com.example.golfandroid.GolfScoreActivity.SetupClickListeners(GolfScoreActivity.java:725)
07-15 16:30:59.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(229):     at com.example.golfandroid.GolfScoreActivity.onCreate(GolfScoreActivity.java:551)
07-15 16:30:59.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(229):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-15 16:30:59.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(229):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
07-15 16:30:59.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(229):     ... 11 more
07-15 16:30:59.432: INFO/Process(61): Sending signal. PID: 229 SIG: 3
07-15 16:30:59.462: INFO/dalvikvm(229): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
07-15 16:30:59.753: INFO/dalvikvm(229): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Code:

```
public void SetupClickListeners(){ 
    for(int holeNum=1; holeNum<18; holeNum++){ 
        scorePlayHole[currentPlayerNum-1][holeNum-1].addTextChangedListener(this); 
    } 
    for(int i=1; i<currentPlayerNum*4; i++){ 
        NextPlayerHoleButton[currentPlayerNum-1][i].setOnClickListener(this); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: How are you creating the arrays?  A "NullPointerException" means you're trying to use a reference that is null.  Since you said it didn't happen until you started using arrays, I'm guessing you didn't initialize them.

Comment: Actually I think the null pointer exception is at line 725 (GolfScoreActivity.SetupClickListeners(GolfScoreActivity.java:725))... So it would be good to see source for (say)551 through 725 +/- a few more for context...

Comment: public void SetupClickListeners(){
        for(int holeNum=1; holeNum<18; holeNum++){
        scorePlayHole[currentPlayerNum-1][holeNum-1].addTextChangedListener(this);
        }
        for(int i=1; i<currentPlayerNum*4; i++){
        NextPlayerHoleButton[currentPlayerNum-1][i].setOnClickListener(this);
        }
 }

Answer (score 1):

This is just a stab in the dark since I only have the stack trace and not the relevant source.

Did you look at this source file? 
GolfScoreActivity.java
Line number 725

Looks like you are setting up a Click Listener but something wasn't initialized and is Null

Comment: How are you people leaving questions under the original question? I don't see the option to comment up there. Is there a minimum score to unlock that feature?

Comment: with add comment but that requires 50 rep - full list here http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark as without seeing the code it's hard to tell - but if you have converted you code to use arrays, did you remember to new the array itself, as well as the objects that go into the array?

Comment: It is an array of EditText which has been initialised and also linked to the ids before I call this method to make a textchangelistener for each EditText. Does anyone fancy volunteering an email address?!

Comment: Given the snippet that you pasted above, it looks to me like the arrays have not been completely initialised and you're getting a null back when you try to retrieve one of the values. You could try to add a log message inside the for loop to print the indexes - that way you will see which iteration is causing the crash. That should help you to identify what hasn't been initialised.

Comment: Thanks ksasq - excuse the ignorance but how do I do that? Will it write to the console or somewhere else?

Comment: Try the functions in android.util.Log - they will output to the device's logcat (same place you are seeing the exception). Alternatively, paste the code where you are filling up the scorePlayHole and NextPlayerHoleButton arrays and we can see what's not initialised right.

Comment: This is difficult to explain but I will try! protected EditText scoreHole1Play1;
.
.
.
EditText[][] scorePlayHole;
.
.
.

scorePlayHole = new EditText[2][18]; 
scorePlayHole[0][0]=scoreHole1Play1;


If I try this print to logcat function it says that 
scorePlayHole[0][0]=null

Why is it null? I have told it that it is an EditText. Does it have to be linked to the id in the layout first?

Comment: How is scoreHole1Play1 initialised?

Comment: You mean given an id? e.g. scorePlayHole[currentPlayerNum][holeNum-1]=(EditText) findViewById(scorePlayHoleID[currentPlayerNum-1][holeNum-1]);

Comment: Yes,something like that - if you have not initialised the  scoreHole1Play1 variable by looking up it's ID (or new-ing it up explicitly), then you will be putting a null object into your array, hence the exception.

Answer (score 0):

`07-15 16:30:59.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(229): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.golfandroid/com.example.golfandroid.GolfScoreActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException`

This isn't really a runtime exception.  It's a runtime exception that wraps a null pointer exception.  The root cause is a null pointer:

After examining your code, any one of these could be `null` and therefore causing the null pointer exception.

`scorePlayHole

scorePlayHole[currentPlayerNum-1]

scorePlayHole[currentPlayerNum-1][holeNum-1]

NextPlayerHoleButton

NextPlayerHoleButton[currentPlayerNum-1]

NextPlayerHoleButton[currentPlayerNum-1][i]`